# Send an email on submission of a Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Whenever users submit a Google Form to my Google Sheet, I want to trigger a OnSubmit function to automatically send an email reply using the email address in the form field, together with a calculated 'right/wrong' data verification of the submission. Since the latest form submission data goes into the last row of the sheet, I tried the following code to pull out both data from the sheet (even though I could use the function parameter for the Email Address).

I also set up the on form submit event trigger and email authorization already. But the emailing doesn't seem to work. Do I still need to run the function in script editor if it is set to trigger on form submission? The code exceeds execution time when I try clicking on Run though.

```
function OnSubmit(e) {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = sheet.getLastRow()-1; 
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows altogether


  // Fetch the range of cells A(last row):G(last row)
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 7);

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
   var row = data[i];
   var emailAddress = row[2];   // Column C of last row
   var message = ""; 
   while(row[6] === "") {     // Delay until data verification is done
     Utilities.sleep(10000);
   }
   var subject = row[6]  // Column G (data verification cell) of last row
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Trace your execution using Logger

Comment: Could you elaborate please? This is my first time trying out Google Apps script. I put the code together based on what I read online.

Comment: You can't use this part of code : `while(row[6] === "") {     // Delay until data verification is done
     Utilities.sleep(10000);
   }` because your data won't be updated during script execution so the loop will always be infinite if row[6] is empty when the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that you are trying to make the script wait until the calculation is complete.

However,

```
while(row[6] === "") {  
 Utilities.sleep(10000);
}
```

is a wrong way to go about this: the variable `row` isn't changing in the loop. It could if the data-fetching line `var data = dataRange.getValues();` was inside of the `while` loop.

But there is a better way to ensure than pending changes actually happen: use

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

before `var data = dataRange.getValues();`

This will apply pending computations, and eliminate the need for that `while` loop.   Result:

```
function OnSubmit(e) {  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 7);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = data[0];
  var emailAddress = row[2];   // Column C of last row
  var message = ""; 
  var subject = row[6]  // Column G (data verification cell) of last row
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out the loop problem! However, the calculated data (col G) is not in the form submission, hence the reason I had to try to pull it out from the last row of the sheet rather than the function parameter. Plus, there is a calculation delay which required a check on whether the calculation is complete before I could pull the data (hence the incorrect use of the loop). Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: OnEdit doesn't seem to work either as the sheet must be open, while this is meant to run with the sheet closed.

Comment: Cool thanks! I saw flush on another code snippet before, but didn't realise that was what it does! Btw, how should I also optimize my code of reading from the last row? The original code I copied from was sending multiple emails at a time, so the code looped through multiple rows, but I actually only need to read the last row.

Comment: Edited answer with an optimized script. I think subtracting 1 from the result of getLastRow was a mistake. getLastRow returns the index of the last row with data, which is what I used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help to get this working! :) Very much appreciated! Upvoted!