# Automatic email response from google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

can anyone help me with on form submit google sheet script  to send email to applicants on data in column c to e, column i and  and column Au on a google sheets?

Thanks in advance for the help!

i have not tried sending the email because am a novice in google form scripting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Cooper has provided an answer using GmailApp. If you would prefer an answer based on MailApp, then look at [Send an email on submission of a Google form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489066/1330560)

Comment: You say that you are _a novice in google form scripting_. In that case, any of the answers here may not be helpful as you don't know what to do with them. If that is the case, I suggest that you look at the two detailed Samples included in the documentation. [Send curated content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/content-signup) on form signup, and [Respond to feedback](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/course-feedback-response) on form submission.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const [,,c,d,e,,,,i,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,au] = e.values;
  const recipient;
  const subject;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject, c + d + e + i + au);
}
```